# undefined method `remove_possible_method' for DateTime:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I am using mina to deploy my application to staging and production servers. Everything worked fine till last month when I ran the mina command to deploy my app, it shows me the error

> mina aborted!
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `remove_possible_method' for
>   DateTime:Class                           Did you mean?  remove_method 
>   /home/tiendo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/compatibility.rb:6:in`
>   '
>   /home/tiendo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/compatibility.rb:3:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>
>   /home/tiendo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time.rb:4:in`
>   require'
>   /home/tiendo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time.rb:4:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>
>   /home/tiendo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:3:in`
>   require'/home/tiendo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:3:in
>   `block in '

The log error is quite long. So, I just copy the beginning of the log. If you guys want to see the full log error. Please let me know, I am going to edit it.

My rails app's version is 5.0.6. Furthermore, I am using rvm and I tried to switch to ruby 2.8.2, 2.3.3, but it still shows me the same error. I've been searching for the solution for a while, but still don't know what causes the error. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Github issue may be related to what you are experiencing 
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28918

Essentially it suggests that you include `require "active_support/core_ext/module/remove_method"` in `activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/compatibility.rb`

Comment: Actually I have seen that issue before. However, this time I decide to require the `active_support/core_ext/module/remove_method` on the top of the file `gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time `. Moreover, I jump to this file by using RubyMine IDE if somebody is wondering how I can jump to that file since it is rails source code and RubyMine allows me to jump to Rails source code instantly whenever I want. I love RubyMine. :)